# GTK themes not displaying correctly

Tags: themes, gtk

Had to reinstall gdm3 and gnome-shell-common and now my GTK themes are not displaying correctly. Using Ubuntu 19.04

Example:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing this:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgtk-3-common light-themes gtk3.0
dconf reset -f /org/compiz
sudo reboot
```

Worked like a charm